# including a specific html element from another site using php echo

Tags: php, html, include, echo, include-path

im brand new to php (started yesterday) ive got a decent background of html/css and a bit of js so i though id give it a shot.

Im trying to build a simple application to teach myself php and i wanted to reference a piece of html from another site, for example the div :

`<div id="name">   <p>Sam</p>     </div>` on the page "http://www.example.com/about.php"

what i was trying was `<?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.example.com #name"); ?>` is that the right way to go about it ?

i was also couldnt work out if it was better to use `include` `echo` or `echo file_get_contents`

sorry for such a basic question

Comment: That'll never work. you can't request just 'part' of a document. You have to transfer the entire page, then use a DOM operation to extract just the portion you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done with [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), here's an example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/');

// get the element that has id=name
$result = $doc->getElementById('name');

echo $result->nodeValue; // prints: Sam

// or print out $result to see all of the properties
print_r($result);
```

Comment: you missed the link probably :(

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob I've missed what?

Comment: seems to work fine, Thank very much !, do you know if it would work if i swapped out the url after loadHTMLfile with a variable ?